# Push object to array, composition api

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

There is an items. With two selection options "size" (large, small) and quantity (2/4/6) each.

When select each option, need to display in the header what is selected (let's say small and 4). By clicking the "add to storage" button, it will add it to the storage, on another page it will display a list.

what i tried:

**vue ts:**

```
const chosenMachines = reactive([]);

const machineInfo = ref({
 size: "Standart",
 glasses: 6
})

const addToList = () => {
 // myStore.addToStoredItems(machineInfo)  ---> storage pinia
 chosenMachines.push(machineInfo.value)
}
```

**template:**

```
<div>Title {{ machineInfo.size  }} | {{ machineInfo.glasses }}</div>       
  <select name="size" v-model='machineInfo.size'  class='selects__select-item'>
    <option>Standart</option>
    <option>Big</option>
  </select>
  <select name="glasses" v-model.number='machineInfo.glasses' class='selects__select-item'>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>8</option>
    <option>12</option>
  </select>
 <button class='btn' @click='sendToStorage'>Add</button>
```

After adding the first object and beyond the second, the first one is overwritten for some reason. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pushing `machineInfo.value` keeps the reference to the original object in the array. You've just made a [shallow copy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Shallow_copy). Any updates to `machineInfo.value` causes the value in the array to also update.  You need to deep copy first before pushing.

```js
chosenMachines.push({...machineInfo.value})
```

There are [many other ways](https://www.samanthaming.com/tidbits/70-3-ways-to-clone-objects/) to deep copy, depending on your data one method may be more suitable than another.